# Import of DLL (c#) using DLL into Python with pythonnet

Tags: python, c#, clr, importerror, dllimport

I am trying to use the DLL 'codessentials.CGM.dll' in python (you can find it in https://www.nuget.org/packages/codessentials.CGM/ or https://github.com/twenzel/CGM).

My goal is to convert a .cgm file in binary encoding to a .cgm file in clear text format. For this, I use the following code :

```
import os, sys, clr

dll_dir = './'
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
path = r'%s%s' % (dll_dir, 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages')
clr.AddReference(path)
path = r'%s%s' % (dll_dir, 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe')
clr.AddReference(path)
path = r'%s%s' % (dll_dir, 'codessentials.CGM')
clr.AddReference(path)

from codessentials.CGM import BinaryCgmFile, ClearTextCgmFile

binaryFile = BinaryCgmFile('test.cgm')
cleanTextFile = ClearTextCgmFile(binaryFile)
content = cleanTextFile.GetContent()
```

The import works but, when I try to use the function 'GetContent', the code yields the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/llyili/PycharmProjects/test_decode_cgm/main.py", line 16, in <module>
    content = cleanTextFile.GetContent()
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Impossible de charger le fichier ou l'assembly 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' ou une de ses dépendances. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.
   à codessentials.CGM.Export.DefaultClearTextWriter..ctor(Stream stream)
   à codessentials.CGM.ClearTextCgmFile.WriteFile(Stream stream)
   à codessentials.CGM.ClearTextCgmFile.GetContent()
```

Is there any way to find out why the import of a DLL used by a DLL is failling ?
I try to import the DLL 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages' with clr, but I can't find the version 4.1.3.0 in Internet so I import the version 5.0.0.0 in the code below.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to write to a folder where you do not have permission or the folder doesn't exist.  What folder is 'test.cgm' located?

Comment: test.cgm is in the same folder than the script. I can open it in the script without problem with the command 'with open('test.cgm') as f:'

Comment: python converts files names to include the full path.  On some versions of python the full path names gets very large.  I had issues on a network path where filenames where over 128 characters and program would not run.  Had to run on my desktop.